# Show value of option when chosen on select in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I'm a newbie in Angular. I have a problem with select tag. I have a list country name and country code. When I chosen an option, I want the result on the select show only country code(value of option) instead of country name and country code.
Example:

```
<select>
  <option value="+1">USA: +1</option>
  <option value="+66">THA: +66</option>
  <option value="+56">CHL: +56</option>
  <option value="+84">VN: +84</option>
</select>
```

When I select the USA, select tag will show "USA: +1" on screen, but I want to only show "+1" in this.

[image]

Have any solutions for this case? If yes, please send me any example code. Thanks so much!

Comment: remove USA form the element

Comment: @Chellappan Can you explain how to do it? Thanks

Comment: is this what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8x8hkc

Comment: @Chellappan No, sir. The element option should be: USA: +1 and when you chosen it. The select lable just show phone code(+1- it's a value of option you choose)

Comment: @Chellappan I updated image for this case

Comment: Assuming your country numbers is an array of objects: `<option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.number">{{country.name}}</option>`

Comment: Hi @Arnoux, Example: number = '+1' and the name="USA: +1". So how to show '+1' after chosen option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the markup, you can define a hidden first option with the default selected value, and set a handler for the `(change)` event:

```
<select (change)="onSelectChange($event)">
  <option hidden value="+1">+1</option>
  <option value="+1">USA: +1</option>
  <option value="+66">THA: +66</option>
  <option value="+56">CHL: +56</option>
  <option value="+84">VN: +84</option>
</select>
```

Every time an option is selected:

- The value of the hidden option is set to the selected value
- The text of the hidden option is set to the selected value
- The hidden option is selected

```
onSelectChange(event: Event) {
  let select = event.target as HTMLSelectElement;
  select.options[0].value = select.value;
  select.options[0].text = select.value;
  select.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpj9z6) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks ConnorsFan. It's worked. But if I want to set "USA: +1" is default selected, how to set it sir?

Comment: @John - I updated the answer and the stackblitz to show `USA: +1` as the default value.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe my question not clear. My question is how to set value '+1' is default value? Because I don't know how to get the select and set it same you do in onSelectChange()

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a demo like this:

```
<select (click)="status=!0" (mouseout)="status=!1" style="width:120px">
    <option value="+1">{{status ? 'USA: ' : ''}}+1</option>
    <option value="+66">{{status ? 'THA: ' : ''}}+66</option>
    <option value="+56">{{status ? 'CHL: ' : ''}}+56</option>
    <option value="+84">{{status ? 'VN: ' : ''}}+84</option>
</select>
```

u can make it better